# WebView in Android & Direct Download Support

Tags: android, webview, download

I've came across many unsolved issues regarding `WebView` with support for downloading files in Android.

Here's the code (whole `MainActivity.java`) for simple `WebView`:

```
package com.webview.downloader;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.pad.android.xappad.AdController;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWeb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWeb = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(mWeb);
        WebSettings settings = mWeb.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
            }
        });
        mWeb.loadUrl("http://www.site-with-direct-links.somehostingsite.com");
    }
}
```

With this code, after opening URL and upon clicking on the link, nothing happens.

We need to add the following code (just right after `mWeb.loadUrl();`):

```
  mWeb.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
      public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
              String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
              long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
      }
  });
```

With this code, now we can surf web and also download files, ex. upon click on something like: *http://www.google.cz*, the `WebView` redirects user to that site, when clicked on: *http://www.google.cz/download-file.apk*, default browser or any other browser like Google Chrome (after choice) will popup for a short time and then Download will start.

So my question is following: how can I achieve to start downloading files (*.zip*, *.rar*, *.apk*) without opening any browser.

Of course, I've looked into docs, also searched stack, but never had a luck with this. Real example would be good, changes to my code sounds even better!

Comment: checkout the answer on this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935214/file-download-not-working-in-android-using-cordova-2-9-0/24646292#24646292