# File download not working in Android using cordova-2.9.0

Tags: html, cordova, download, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-2.7.0

I am working on a hybird application and it seems very straightforward way to download a pdf file from server using HTML5 anchor download attribute and this is working exactly as expected using below code on desktop browsers.

```
<a href="/path/sample.pdf" download="Test.pdf">Download</a>
```

Challange: But when I am trying to run same code in my Hybird application, using cordova 2.9.0 , when debugging app on mobile; on clicking of Download nothing shows up and download does not start.

Am I missing something very basic here?

Please suggest.

Comment: Android web views currently do not support the download attribute. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=432414#makechanges

Answer (score 3):

This code is for Android platform.
First, open the file `[appname].java` in your platform folder:
`appname\platforms\android\src\com\[appname]\app`
Next, set downloadListener for the webview, right after `super.init();`

here is the complete code:

```
package com.[appname].app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class [appname] extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();   

        super.appView.setDownloadListener(new android.webkit.DownloadListener() {

            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

                android.util.Log.d("Logger","url : " + url  + " userAgent: " + userAgent + " contentDisposition: " + contentDisposition + " mimeType: " + mimetype + " contentLength " + contentLength);                        

                android.net.Uri source = android.net.Uri.parse(url);

                // Make a new request
                android.app.DownloadManager.Request request = new android.app.DownloadManager.Request(source);

                // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading               
                String filename = getFilename(contentDisposition);

                request.setDescription("This file will be saved in your downloads folder.");
                request.setTitle(filename);

                //add cookie on request header (for authenticated web app)
                String cookieContent = getCookieFromAppCookieManager(source.getHost());             
                request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookieContent);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(android.app.DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }

                // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename); 

                // get download service and enqueue file
                android.app.DownloadManager manager = (android.app.DownloadManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                manager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });

        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    };

    public String getFilename(String contentDisposition){
        String filename[] = contentDisposition.split("filename=");
        return filename[1].replace("filename=", "").replace("\"", "").trim();
    };

    public String getCookieFromAppCookieManager(String url){
        android.webkit.CookieManager cookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
        if (cookieManager == null)
            return null;
        String rawCookieHeader = null;

        // Extract Set-Cookie header value from Android app CookieManager for this URL
        rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
        if (rawCookieHeader == null)
            return null;

        return rawCookieHeader;
    };

}
```

Comment: This won't work. See my comment above. Android web views just don't support the download attribute.